# Error (re)generating entity with jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I created a JHipster gateway project, and I would add some informations to User entity. With

```
jhipster entity User --regenerate
```

I got this error :

```
Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
Executing jhipster:entity User
Options: regenerate: true
events.js:160
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at getAngularAppName (/home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1786:65)
    at getConfig (/home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/entity/index.js:162:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:399:25)
    at /home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
    at /home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/home/denis/ngworkspace/sensorgw/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:400:11)
    at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

I have same error when I create a entity and with option --force.

I use openSuse Leap42.3, yarn 1.2.1, node v6.11.1, npm 3.10.10 and my project has been created with jhipster 4.9.0.

I upgraded jhipster to last version 4.10.2, and I cannot upgrade my project (same error).

Thanks, Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have seen `getAngularAppName()` fails due to `this.baseName` being null, please check that `.yo-rc.json` contans a `baseName` property.
Check also that you don't have a `.yo-rc.json` file in a parent directory.

Comment: I had a ./node_modules/jhipster-core/test/test_files/jhipster_app/.yo-rc.json. I copied in project root, and that works ! Thanks

Comment: That's not what I meant and you should not have done this as .yo-rc.json file contains all the answers when you generated your project. Copying it from a test app is really a bad idea, now you have a monolith using mysql, jwt, elasticsearch, kafka, web sockets and the jhipster registry !!!!

Comment: ok, I didn't read the file. So, I just creating  new project with same answer to questions, and copy the .yo.rc.json file in my project. Is it the correct fix ?

Comment: Yes and understand why your old file disappeared